# How to make the censor mark just reach the survival line, not cross it?

Tags: r

```
library("survminer") 
fit2<- survfit(Surv(OS..months., Survival.status) ~ Gender, data = inputdata) 
ggsurvplot(fit2, data = inputdata, censor=TRUE, censor.shape = 124)
```

The code is like this, I don't want the censor mark to cross the line, just to reach it. In other words, I just want the upper part of the mark. How can this be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide sample `inputdata`? Also, survminer_0.4.6 has `surv_fit` but not `survfit`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`censor.shape="'"` 
Default value is "+".

`ggsurvplot(fit2, data = inputdata, censor=TRUE, censor.shape ="'")`